# Google Authorization Failure Error

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I am using Android 2.3.6 Device for testing. When I run the Google Map android api v2 on the device it doesnot show the map on the device and also show the error on logcat as follows

Google Maps Android API            Authorization failure.

Also on the Console It shows the

[2012-12-07 13:59:42 - google-play-services_lib] Could not find google-play-services_lib.apk!

Please Help Me!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

I also found that the play services libproject has to be imported onto the same *physical drive* as your project. (which may not be the case if you didn't check the 'Copy projects into workspace' checkbox)

Answer (score 0):

[Setting up a Library Project](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject)

I just added the project of google services and added a reference in my project property->Android
check above link.

Answer (score 0):

First of all download the latest google play services revision 3.
Import the google play services libproject as a library in Eclipse. 
Then go to properties>Android and below add the above project as a library to your project.
Also ensure that the google play services are updated on your device.Use the debug keystore if you are directly running the app on the device.You will have to add the sha1 print and package of the debug keystore while creating Android key.

> Refer to this example :
>   https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=19nQzvKP-CVLd7_VrpwnHfl-AE9fjbJySowONZZtNHzw

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately for using the Google Maps you have to test the application on a real device as the emulator is not supported.